# How to show that projections are diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $E$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $E^2=E.$ Then we know that $E$ is a projection and in particular, every $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as $v=Ev+(v-Ev).$

If $\mathcal{B}_1$ are the basis for the $\text{Im}(E)$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ for $\ker (E)$ then I know that the basis for $V$ is the set $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}_1\cup \mathcal{B}_2.$ Now I want to show that the matrix $[E]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is diagonalizable. Note that a similar question has been already asked on this website, however, I am more interested in knowing whether the following will work and if not why?

So I know that if $\mathcal{B}=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_r,\alpha_{r+1},...,\alpha_{n}\}$ where the first $r$ elements are in $\mathcal{B}_1$ and the remaining in $\mathcal{B}_2.$ The the elements of the matrix are $1\leq j\leq r$

$$E(\alpha_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}\alpha_{i}.$$ And $0$ elsewhere because if we pick $\alpha_{r+1}$ for instance then $E(\alpha_{r+1})=0$ and so $$0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ir+1}\alpha_{i}\implies \text{ all the coefficients are 0 as the vectors are linearly independent}. $$

So the goal is to somehow show that for each $1\leq j\leq r$ we have $a_{ij}=0$ for each $i\not =j.$ This is where I am facing some trouble.

Maybe we can go by contradiction. Say $a_{ij}=k\not=0$ where $i\not =j.$

Edit:

How about $$E(\alpha_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}\alpha_{i}\implies E(\alpha_{j}-\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_{ij}\alpha_{i})=0$$ Thus $\alpha_{j}-\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_{ij}\alpha_{i}=0$. Implying that $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}.$

Comment: There already a slick answer, but another way to see it is that it is easy to construct a basis for the image and a basis for the kernel which together make a basis for the space consisting of linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Use the fact that the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors. That gives you the last $n-r$ columns as zero immediately, and what you’re left with is showing that the restriction of $E$ to $\operatorname{Im}(E)$ is the identity map. [José Carlos Santos’ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2584873/265466), below, gives an easy proof of that.

Comment: You could use the fact that $\dim \ker E + \dim \ker (I-E) = n$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that each $\alpha_j$ (with $1\leqslant j\leqslant r$) is in the image of $E$. So, $\alpha_j=E(\beta_j)$ and therefore$$E(\alpha_j)=E\bigl(E(\beta_j)\bigr)=E(\beta_j)=\alpha_j.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $p(x):=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ then $p(E)=0$ and $m_E\mid p(x)$. But $p(x)$ can be linearly factored and then $m_E$ too, that implies $E$ diagonalizable.

Comment: Sorry, but yes... Remember that dim$V<\infty$

Comment: A nilpotent endomorphism has $\chi(x)=x^k$. If the minimal is $m(x)=x$ then is the null endomorphism!

Comment: $m_E$ must be the product of *distinct* linear factors for $E$ to be diagonalizable.

Comment: @amd: yep, you nailed it!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg haha. I did not understand. It is common to call "linearly factored" when the factors are strictly different

Comment: Ah, with that convention your answer is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E^2 = E$, the minimal polynomial $m_E(x)$ of $E$ divides $x^2-x = x(x-1)$. So $m_E(x)$ is either $x$, $x-1$, or $x(x-1)$. Since it is a product of distinct monic linear factors, $E$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: No, $x^2-x$ see my answer

Comment: You're right, I slipped badly there. Fixing it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's even simpler than that. The image and the kernel of $E$ (which are respectively the eigenstates associated to the eigenvalues $1$ and $0$) form à direct sum of the total space. The matrix of $E$ in a basis obtained by juxtaposition of basis of these spaces is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

A linear operator $E$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial of $E$ has no repeated roots. The minimal polynomial of $E$ must divide $m(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)$, from which the result follows.